# <option> по умолчанию без возможности его выбрать

Tags: html, css

Каким образом можно реализовать такой пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если добавить атрибут disabled, то эта опция не видна по умолчанию. Нужно что бы при выпадении списка его не было, а по умолчанию он был

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="" disabled>Выберите способ оплаты</option>
    <option value="Наличными">Наличными</option>
    <option value="Другим способом">Другим способом</option>
</select>
```

Стилизовать буду потом, интересует именно этот момент пока что.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Укажите у `<option>` атрибуты `disabled selected hidden`

```html
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Выберите способ оплаты</option>
    <option value="Наличными">Наличными</option>
    <option value="Другим способом">Другим способом</option>
</select>
```

В IE11 и ниже из списка не скрывает, но и не позволяет выбрать.

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно